# Flutter Habit Tracker - How to make a button clickable only once a day

Tags: flutter

I want to build a habit tracker for myself and I want, that the buttons (habits) are clickable once a day.

Comment: I would suggest you to learn flutter :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backend service like firebase you can check the database to see when was the last time that the user clicked the button and then either allow or disable the onPressed OR use shared_preferences if you don't want to deal with backends simply store the Date object in a String and check that